# .htaccess WP-admin url twice

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am unable to access my WordPress site URL, it redirects like

```
http://www.mydomain.net/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.net%2Fmydomain.net%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

but it shoud redirect to

```
http://www.mydomain.net/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.net%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I believe the problem is with .htaccess file as I am rewriting the path of folder like

`public_html/mydomain.net`

instead of `public_html` as this domain is primary domain of cPanel but to avoid confusing, I created a directory and rewriting path using .htaccess.

There is nothing wrong with WordPress. In settings>general both the URLs set to `mydomain.net`

**.htaccess code is** Placed in Public_HTML

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mydomain.net/
RewriteRule (.*) /mydomain.net/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after changing the root directory of my blog (before migration) and trying to coming back... Changing the data in my DB was not working for me.

I still did not figure out why but I had a "page not found" when I tried to access categories, tags,... and even on the home page. Links to articles worked correcly and the administration page was not accessible (wp-admin rewritten twice in the url).

These actions solved my problem:

> 1. Edit the wp-config.php file.
> 2. After the "define" statements (just before the comment line that says "That's all, stop editing!"), insert a new line, and type:
>      define('RELOCATE',true);
> 3. Save your wp-config.php file.
> 4. Open a web browser and manually point it to wp-login.php on the new server.

I had to change the value of the root directory in the administration page (after these actions gave me back the access to it).

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method for more info.